# Symfony2 assets:install base resources

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony2 you can do a `assets:install` to copy your assets to the web (or another folder). Is there a way to do an `assets:install` for the public folder in `app/Resources` or do you just have to place them inside the web folder?

Thanks

Comment: no.. you just need to place the css and js and the images in the main Web/ files

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `MainBundle` or `CoreBundle` regrouping every common assets in its `public/` folder. 
Sooner or later you'll probably need this bundle anyway to store common services etc.

Answer (score -1):

it is better to put them directly in web folder and use this function to link them

```
 href="{{ asset('css/screen.css') }}
```